# Доступ к локальным файлам на сервере развернутом на Heroku

Tags: tomcat, heroku

Как выглядит директория в tomcat на heroku host?

У меня была стандартно в том кат папка ROOT и там webapp, там хранил файлы, но когда залил проект на хостинг выдает ошибку что не найден файл

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    String PATH_SEPARATOR = "/";
    String WILD_MATCH = "**";
    registry.addResourceHandler(PATH_SEPARATOR + "media" + PATH_SEPARATOR + WILD_MATCH)
            .addResourceLocations("file:///" + sourcesPath().toString() + File.separator + "productPhoto" + File.separator)
            .resourceChain(false)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
}


@Bean
public Path sourcesPath() {
    return Paths.get(System.getProperty("catalina.home")+ File.separator + "webapps"+
                                                              File.separator + "ROOT" +
                                                              File.separator + "static" + File.separator);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал рекурсию которая ходила по папкам и выводила их, оказалось что структура выглядит так

```
System.getProperty("catalina.home")+ File.separator + "webapps"+
                                     File.separator + "expanded" /*"ROOT"*/+
                                     File.separator + "myresources");
```

Answer (score 0):

Откуда ссылаетесь на файлы?? из контроллеров или jsp(servlets)?
если из контроллеров или бинов..то нужно использовать    `'File.separator'.У меня только что была такая проблема ..решился..

у меня на spring mvc контроллер выглядит так..

```
 @ResponseBody
        @RequestMapping(value = "selhoztehnicajaxphoto", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
        public byte[] selhoztehnicajaxphoto() throws IOException {
            InputStream in=null;
            String rootPath = "path\\";
            File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "photos");
            File f = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "2.jpg");
            in = new FileInputStream(f);

            return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
        }
```

Comment: Все равно не хочет загружать, хотя на локальной версии все супер

Comment: что это за файлы??

Comment: у меня было точно так же.

Comment: картинки, которые открываются по url media/название картинки